# Create a multidimensional array from sql query result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

Using this query I am getting this array as a result. but some rows are repeating with some distinct columns. what I want to do is take those distinct columns in to a separate array as a multidimensional array of the parent array. I tried to do it with Mysql group_by distinct clause but I couldn't do it. I think best way is to make it by php. Please give me a little help with this thing. Thanks
Myquery

```
$query = "SELECT "
                . "a.emp_nmbr, a.emp_frstNm, a.emp_lstNm, a.emp_lclFrn, b.emp_dsgntn, b.emp_dprtmnt, b.emp_allwncs, b.emp_bscSlry, b.emp_sts, c.emp_lvsCtgry, c.emp_tknFrm, c.emp_tknTo "
                . "FROM "
                . "employee a "
                . "LEFT JOIN "
                . "emp_details b "
                . "ON "
                . "a.emp_nmbr = b.emp_nmbr "
                . "LEFT JOIN "
                . "leaves_details c "
                . "ON "
                . "a.emp_nmbr = c.emp_nmbr "                
                . "WHERE emp_lclFrn = 0 ";
                . "LIMIT $page, $perPage ";
```

codeigniter model function to execute query.

```
function count_and_data($query) {
        $query = $this->db->query($query);
        $result = $query->result();
        $count = $query->num_rows();
        $data['count'] = $count;
        $data['rows'] = $result;
        return $data;
    }
```

The result array I am getting

```
Array
(
    [count] => 16
    [rows] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl3
                    [emp_frstNm] => aaaaaaaa
                    [emp_lstNm] => saaa
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => test
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 0
                    [emp_allwncs] => a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:7:"alwncNm";s:4:"food";s:9:"alwncAmnt";s:3:"456";}i:1;a:2:{s:7:"alwncNm";s:0:"";s:9:"alwncAmnt";s:0:"";}}
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 2555
                    [emp_sts] => 4
                    [emp_lvsCtgry] => 1
                    [emp_tknFrm] => 20141222
                    [emp_tknTo] => 20141223
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl3
                    [emp_frstNm] => aaaaaaaa
                    [emp_lstNm] => saaa
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => test
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 0
                    [emp_allwncs] => a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:7:"alwncNm";s:4:"food";s:9:"alwncAmnt";s:3:"456";}i:1;a:2:{s:7:"alwncNm";s:0:"";s:9:"alwncAmnt";s:0:"";}}
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 2555
                    [emp_sts] => 4
                    [emp_lvsCtgry] => 3
                    [emp_tknFrm] => 20141223
                    [emp_tknTo] => 20141224
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl3
                    [emp_frstNm] => aaaaaaaa
                    [emp_lstNm] => saaa
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => test
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 0
                    [emp_allwncs] => a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:7:"alwncNm";s:4:"food";s:9:"alwncAmnt";s:3:"456";}i:1;a:2:{s:7:"alwncNm";s:0:"";s:9:"alwncAmnt";s:0:"";}}
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 2555
                    [emp_sts] => 4
                    [emp_lvsCtgry] => 4
                    [emp_tknFrm] => 20141224
                    [emp_tknTo] => 20141231
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl14
                    [emp_frstNm] => qqq
                    [emp_lstNm] => qqqq
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => test
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 0
                    [emp_allwncs] => a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:7:"alwncNm";s:5:"qqqqq";s:9:"alwncAmnt";s:4:"2222";}i:1;a:2:{s:7:"alwncNm";s:0:"";s:9:"alwncAmnt";s:0:"";}}
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 2222
                    [emp_sts] => 3
                    [emp_lvsCtgry] => 
                    [emp_tknFrm] => 
                    [emp_tknTo] => 
                )

            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl1
                    [emp_frstNm] => yas
                    [emp_lstNm] => yas
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => 
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 
                    [emp_allwncs] => 
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 
                    [emp_sts] => 
                    [emp_lvsCtgry] => 
                    [emp_tknFrm] => 
                    [emp_tknTo] => 
                )

            [5] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl2
                    [emp_frstNm] => test
                    [emp_lstNm] => test
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => 
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 
                    [emp_allwncs] => 
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 
                    [emp_sts] => 
                    [emp_lvsCtgry] => 
                    [emp_tknFrm] => 
                    [emp_tknTo] => 
                )

            [6] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl4
                    [emp_frstNm] => yaa
                    [emp_lstNm] => yaaa
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => 
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 
                    [emp_allwncs] => 
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 
                    [emp_sts] => 
                    [emp_lvsCtgry] => 
                    [emp_tknFrm] => 
                    [emp_tknTo] => 
                )

            [7] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl5
                    [emp_frstNm] => sdfds
                    [emp_lstNm] => sdfsdf
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => 
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 
                    [emp_allwncs] => 
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 
                    [emp_sts] => 
                    [emp_lvsCtgry] => 
                    [emp_tknFrm] => 
                    [emp_tknTo] => 
                )

            [8] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl6
                    [emp_frstNm] => fsdfsdf
                    [emp_lstNm] => sfsdfsdf
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => 
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 
                    [emp_allwncs] => 
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 
                    [emp_sts] => 
                    [emp_lvsCtgry] => 
                    [emp_tknFrm] => 
                    [emp_tknTo] => 
                )

            [9] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl7
                    [emp_frstNm] => fsdfsdf
                    [emp_lstNm] => sfsdfsdf
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => 
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 
                    [emp_allwncs] => 
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 
                    [emp_sts] => 
                    [emp_lvsCtgry] => 
                    [emp_tknFrm] => 
                    [emp_tknTo] => 
                )

            [10] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl8
                    [emp_frstNm] => yyyyyyyyy
                    [emp_lstNm] => yyyyyyy
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => 
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 
                    [emp_allwncs] => 
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 
                    [emp_sts] => 
                    [emp_lvsCtgry] => 
                    [emp_tknFrm] => 
                    [emp_tknTo] => 
                )

            [11] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl9
                    [emp_frstNm] => sfdsf
                    [emp_lstNm] => sfdsdfsdf
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => 
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 
                    [emp_allwncs] => 
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 
                    [emp_sts] => 
                    [emp_lvsCtgry] => 
                    [emp_tknFrm] => 
                    [emp_tknTo] => 
                )

            [12] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl10
                    [emp_frstNm] => test
                    [emp_lstNm] => test
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => 
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 
                    [emp_allwncs] => 
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 
                    [emp_sts] => 
                    [emp_lvsCtgry] => 
                    [emp_tknFrm] => 
                    [emp_tknTo] => 
                )

            [13] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl11
                    [emp_frstNm] => test
                    [emp_lstNm] => test
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => 
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 
                    [emp_allwncs] => 
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 
                    [emp_sts] => 
                    [emp_lvsCtgry] => 
                    [emp_tknFrm] => 
                    [emp_tknTo] => 
                )

            [14] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl12
                    [emp_frstNm] => ssss
                    [emp_lstNm] => sss
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => 
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 
                    [emp_allwncs] => 
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 
                    [emp_sts] => 
                    [emp_lvsCtgry] => 
                    [emp_tknFrm] => 
                    [emp_tknTo] => 
                )

            [15] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl13
                    [emp_frstNm] => yaas
                    [emp_lstNm] => yaas
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => 
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 
                    [emp_allwncs] => 
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 
                    [emp_sts] => 
                    [emp_lvsCtgry] => 
                    [emp_tknFrm] => 
                    [emp_tknTo] => 
                )

        )

)
```

What I am Expecting is

```
Array
(
    [count] => 16
    [rows] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl3
                    [emp_frstNm] => aaaaaaaa
                    [emp_lstNm] => saaa
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => test
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 0
                    [emp_allwncs] => a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:7:"alwncNm";s:4:"food";s:9:"alwncAmnt";s:3:"456";}i:1;a:2:{s:7:"alwncNm";s:0:"";s:9:"alwncAmnt";s:0:"";}}
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 2555
                    [emp_sts] => 4
                    [emp_lvData]=>array(
                        array[0](
                                [emp_lvsCtgry] => 1
                                [emp_tknFrm] => 20141222
                                [emp_tknTo] => 20141223
                              )
                         array[1](
                                [emp_lvsCtgry] => 3
                                [emp_tknFrm] => 20141223
                                [emp_tknTo] => 20141224
                              )
                         array[2](
                                [emp_lvsCtgry] => 4
                                [emp_tknFrm] => 20141224
                                [emp_tknTo] => 20141231
                              )

                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl14
                    [emp_frstNm] => qqq
                    [emp_lstNm] => qqqq
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => test
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 0
                    [emp_allwncs] => a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:7:"alwncNm";s:5:"qqqqq";s:9:"alwncAmnt";s:4:"2222";}i:1;a:2:{s:7:"alwncNm";s:0:"";s:9:"alwncAmnt";s:0:"";}}
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 2222
                    [emp_sts] => 3
                    [emp_lvData]=>array(
                        array[0](
                                [emp_lvsCtgry] => 1
                                [emp_tknFrm] => 20141222
                                [emp_tknTo] => 20141223
                              )
                          )
                )

            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl1
                    [emp_frstNm] => yas
                    [emp_lstNm] => yas
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => 
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 
                    [emp_allwncs] => 
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 
                    [emp_sts] => 
                    [emp_lvData]=>array(
                        array[0](
                                [emp_lvsCtgry] => 1
                                [emp_tknFrm] => 20141222
                                [emp_tknTo] => 20141223
                              )
                         )
                )

            [5] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl2
                    [emp_frstNm] => test
                    [emp_lstNm] => test
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => 
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 
                    [emp_allwncs] => 
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 
                    [emp_sts] => 
                    [emp_lvData]=>array(
                        array[0](
                                [emp_lvsCtgry] => 1
                                [emp_tknFrm] => 20141222
                                [emp_tknTo] => 20141223
                              )
                          )
                )

            [6] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl4
                    [emp_frstNm] => yaa
                    [emp_lstNm] => yaaa
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => 
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 
                    [emp_allwncs] => 
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 
                    [emp_sts] => 
                    [emp_lvData]=>array(
                        array[0](
                                [emp_lvsCtgry] => 1
                                [emp_tknFrm] => 20141222
                                [emp_tknTo] => 20141223
                              )
                         )
                )

            [7] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl5
                    [emp_frstNm] => sdfds
                    [emp_lstNm] => sdfsdf
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => 
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 
                    [emp_allwncs] => 
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 
                    [emp_sts] => 
                    [emp_lvData]=>array(
                        array[0](
                                [emp_lvsCtgry] => 1
                                [emp_tknFrm] => 20141222
                                [emp_tknTo] => 20141223
                              )
                         )
                )

            [8] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl6
                    [emp_frstNm] => fsdfsdf
                    [emp_lstNm] => sfsdfsdf
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => 
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 
                    [emp_allwncs] => 
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 
                    [emp_sts] => 
                    [emp_lvData]=>array(
                        array[0](
                                [emp_lvsCtgry] => 1
                                [emp_tknFrm] => 20141222
                                [emp_tknTo] => 20141223
                              )
                           )
                )

            [9] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl7
                    [emp_frstNm] => fsdfsdf
                    [emp_lstNm] => sfsdfsdf
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => 
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 
                    [emp_allwncs] => 
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 
                    [emp_sts] => 
                    [emp_lvData]=>array(
                        array[0](
                                [emp_lvsCtgry] => 1
                                [emp_tknFrm] => 20141222
                                [emp_tknTo] => 20141223
                              )
                         ) 
                )

            [10] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl8
                    [emp_frstNm] => yyyyyyyyy
                    [emp_lstNm] => yyyyyyy
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => 
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 
                    [emp_allwncs] => 
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 
                    [emp_sts] => 
                    [emp_lvData]=>array(
                        array[0](
                                [emp_lvsCtgry] => 1
                                [emp_tknFrm] => 20141222
                                [emp_tknTo] => 20141223
                              )
                          )
                )

            [11] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl9
                    [emp_frstNm] => sfdsf
                    [emp_lstNm] => sfdsdfsdf
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => 
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 
                    [emp_allwncs] => 
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 
                    [emp_sts] => 
                    [emp_lvData]=>array(
                        array[0](
                                [emp_lvsCtgry] => 1
                                [emp_tknFrm] => 20141222
                                [emp_tknTo] => 20141223
                              )
                           )
                )

            [12] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl10
                    [emp_frstNm] => test
                    [emp_lstNm] => test
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => 
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 
                    [emp_allwncs] => 
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 
                    [emp_sts] => 
                    [emp_lvData]=>array(
                        array[0](
                                [emp_lvsCtgry] => 1
                                [emp_tknFrm] => 20141222
                                [emp_tknTo] => 20141223
                              )
                          )
                )

            [13] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl11
                    [emp_frstNm] => test
                    [emp_lstNm] => test
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => 
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 
                    [emp_allwncs] => 
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 
                    [emp_sts] => 
                    [emp_lvData]=>array(
                        array[0](
                                [emp_lvsCtgry] => 1
                                [emp_tknFrm] => 20141222
                                [emp_tknTo] => 20141223
                              )
                         ) 
                )

            [14] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl12
                    [emp_frstNm] => ssss
                    [emp_lstNm] => sss
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => 
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 
                    [emp_allwncs] => 
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 
                    [emp_sts] => 
                    [emp_lvData]=>array(
                        array[0](
                                [emp_lvsCtgry] => 1
                                [emp_tknFrm] => 20141222
                                [emp_tknTo] => 20141223
                              )
                           )
                )

            [15] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [emp_nmbr] => ophl13
                    [emp_frstNm] => yaas
                    [emp_lstNm] => yaas
                    [emp_lclFrn] => 0
                    [emp_dsgntn] => 
                    [emp_dprtmnt] => 
                    [emp_allwncs] => 
                    [emp_bscSlry] => 
                    [emp_sts] => 
                    [emp_lvData]=>array(
                        array[0](
                                [emp_lvsCtgry] => 1
                                [emp_tknFrm] => 20141222
                                [emp_tknTo] => 20141223
                              )
                           )
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I think you can use a `foreach` loop the sql result and get you want.

Comment: @LLL - But how to remove those repeating rows

Comment: First, I think your structure should be change something. And I have write a sample code to push same key value to a array. I hope that will help for your. https://gist.github.com/c11c1fbbd48321354d1f.git

Comment: @LLL - your link is not working can please check it.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/lighter/c11c1fbbd48321354d1f

Comment: @lll - Sorry this doesn't do anything

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick flow that helps you to achieve your requirenment.

```
// collect all the unique data here
$holder = array();

foreach($data['rows'] as $data) {

    // check with emp_nmbr = ophl3
    if( ( $key = _finder($data->emp_nmbr, $holder) ) === false ) {
        $holder[] = array(
            'emp_nmbr'=>$data->emp_nmbr, 
            ..........
            'emp_lvData'=>array(
                array('emp_lvsCtgry'=>$data->emp_lvsCtgry)
                ..........
            )
        );
    }
    else {
        // emp_nmbr = ophl3 found now Merge Data Here.. 
        if( ! empty( $data->emp_lvsCtgry ) ) {
            $holder[$key]['emp_lvData'] = 
                 array_merge( 
                     $holder[$key]['emp_lvData'], 
                     array('emp_lvsCtgry'=>$data->emp_lvsCtgry));
        }   
    }

}

// Search Value in Muliti-dimentional array
function _finder($key, $array) {

    if( ! is_array($array) || count($array) == 0 ) return false;

    foreach( $array as $k=>$arr ){
         if( in_array( $key, $arr ) ) {
             return $key;
         }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Where `$holder` holds all your unique array data.

Comment: I feel this will do the work but. still I am getting some errors

Comment: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array (this error two times)
 Undefined index: ophl3
both errors are in this line 
$holder[$key]['emp_lvData'] = array_merge($holder[$key]['emp_lvData'], array('' => $data->emp_lvsCtgry));

Comment: @Yasitha you have to check the array first, because in some cases you don't have value in `emp_lvsCtgry`

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you. I checked your updated code. it is returning only emp_lvsCtgry for each employee. if I tried to add other details to $holder array then it is again giving the same three errors as above. I change your code from $holder[] = array(
                    'emp_lvData' => array(
                        array('emp_lvsCtgry' => $data->emp_lvsCtgry)
                    ) 
to $holder[] = array(
                    'emp_nmbr' => $data->emp_nmbr,
                    'emp_lvData' => array(
                        array('emp_lvsCtgry' => $data->emp_lvsCtgry)
                    )